# Pre-Rendering index.html in Svelte (without SvelteKit)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, svelte

I am using Vite Svelte with the default config, and I need to pre-render the main html file in svelte, however I do not want to use the SvelteKit static page generator. The Svelte compiler generates an `index.html`, and a JS bundle, which contains all the infomation. The index.html is empty and only used for importing the bundle. The problem being that BingBot, with my experience does not run JS, therefore my page never gets indexed.

How do I set it up to pre render index.html when generating static files without using SvelteKit in my stack?

Comment: "The Svelte compiler generates an index.html", no it doesn't. What is your build system? Also show its configs.